# Using buttons wrapped in DIV elements to scroll to specific sections of the page

Tags: javascript, html, button

Ok I have different sections for my homepage.

This is the code of the menu bar:

```
<div class="col-xs-10 text-right menu-1 main-nav">
  <ul>
    <li class="active"><a href="#" data-nav-section="home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-nav-section="services">Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-nav-section="about">About Digm</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-nav-section="contact">Contact Us</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" data-nav-section="audit"><b>FREE Audit</b></a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

These work fine as far as going to the sections I need them to is concerned.

But I also have buttons wrapped in DIV elements for a slideshow. The buttons work if I make them external links to leave my site, but they won't let me use them to go to the same sections I can go to with the menu bar links.

These are the DIVs with the buttons:

```
<div id="ubea-hero" class="js-fullheight" data-section="home">
  <div class="flexslider js-fullheight">
    <ul class="slides">
      <li style="background-image: url(images/img_bg_1.jpg);">
        <div class="overlay"></div>
        <div class="container">
          <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1 text-center js-fullheight slider-text">
            <div class="slider-text-inner">
              <h2>It's time to shift strategies.</h2>
              <p><a href="#audit" data-nav-section="audit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">FREE Audit</a></p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        </li>
        <li style="background-image: url(images/img_bg_2.jpg);">
        <div class="overlay"></div>
        <div class="container">
          <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1 text-center js-fullheight slider-text">
            <div class="slider-text-inner" text-align: center>
              <h2>Experience The Butterfly<br />Effect</h2>
                <p><a href="#aboutdigm" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-nav-section="about">Read More</a></p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li style="background-image: url(images/img_bg_3.jpg);">
        <div class="overlay"></div>
        <div class="container">
          <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1 text-center js-fullheight slider-text">
            <div class="slider-text-inner" text-align: center>
              <h2>Ready? Book A Consultation</h2>
              <p><a href="#" target="_blank" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Why Wait?</a></p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

The code I have for 1 the sections looks like this:

```
<div id="ubea-contact" data-section="contact" class="ubea-cover ubea-cover-xs" style="background-image:url(images/img_bg_2.jpg);">
  <div class="overlay"></div>
  <div class="ubea-container">
    <div class="row text-center">
      <div class="display-t">
        <div class="display-tc">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <h3>If you have inquiries please email us at <a href="#"><b>info@blahblahblah.com</b></a></h3>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Anyone see why the buttons won't scroll to the sections?

Answer (score 1):

Anchor elements `href` property does that by default. Simply give the target element the `id` attribute matching the `href="#introduction"` on the menu anchor.

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#intro" data-nav-section="services">Intro</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>

<h4 id="intro">Intro</h4>
<p>Foo bar.</p>
```

Comment: This is essentially what I have now but it's not working for some reason. I believe the buttons being in a DIV has something to do with that.

Answer (score 0):

What does your CSS look like?

You could always use JavaScript:

```
// we can't use "forEach" on a NodeList, since it's an Array prototype
var forEach = [].forEach;
// listen for an "onclick" event on the target button
document.getElementById("button_id").addEventListener("click", function() {
  // select the target slide
  var slide = document.getElementById("slide_1");
  // show the target slide
  slide.style.display = "block";
  // hide the slides siblings
  forEach.call(slide.parentNode.children, function(s) {
    // NOTE: don't hide the target slide!
    if(s !== slide) {
      s.style.display = none;
    }
  });
});
```

Or if you prefer, you could just use jQuery:

```
$("#button_id").on("click", function() {
  $(this).show().siblings().hide();
});
```

Also, avoid using so many div's, try to use [semantic tags](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Semantics) instead.

Too many `div`'s will make your code hard to maintain and the overuse of the `div` tag can lead to a [`div soup`](https://www.pluralsight.com/blog/software-development/html5-web-components-overview), which can be horrible to maintain.

Good luck.

Comment: Yeah you're right about all the DIV's. I was essentially working with someone else's code and I'm honestly not sure of how to clean it up I was working within the format. How would the JS or jQuery code you provided supplement what's there already exactly?